# Application not Installed error when referencing Mono.Android.GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android, kindle-fire, xamarin

I am working on a new update to my app and added google maps support.  I added a reference to the Mono.Android.GoogleMaps assembly.  All works great, tested good on my Droid X device so I sent the .apk to beta testers.  I then tried to install on my Kindle Fire (allowed unknown sources) and it failed to install.  I also got a report from a beta tester that they got the same message on their Motorola Photon.

I've later learned Kindle Fire and NOOK don't have the Google Maps integration.  I've already built around "location" permissions although not sure if that was required.

I just fired up a AVD for Kindle Fire per the Amazon info and tried deploying a debug build.  I got this error message:

[image: Deploy error to Kindle Fire emulator AVD]

How do you suggest I proceed?  If this issue IS google maps being referenced, how do you handle this so my app will run on devices without this shared library present?  What do I test for in code as to when to allow features such as this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched the issue and added this line to my AssemblyInfo.cs and now it installs to Kindle Fire.

```
[assembly: UsesLibrary(Name="com.google.android.maps", Required=false)]
```